# Cannot convert type to type* - C++ compile error

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

I am trying to create a dynamic array of type 'T' that contains an array of type 'X'. In order to access attributes of T from X, I tried creating a pointer in struct X that points to T. This is the code I have:

```
struct WireSeg; // Forward declaration

struct Track { // Type X in above description
    int trackNum;
    bool used;
    WireSeg* parentWireSeg;
};

struct WireSeg { // Type T in above description
    int xCoord; 
    int yCoord;
    char flag;
    char orientation;
    Track* track;
};

typedef WireSeg* WireSegPtr

int main (void) {
  WireSegPtr wireSeg;
  wireSeg = new WireSeg[5];
  for (int i =0; i<5; i++) {
    wireSeg[i].track = new Track[3];
    for (int j =0; j<3; j++) {
      wireSeg[i].track[j].parentWireSeg = wireSeg[i];
    }
  }
}
```

I get the compile error:

> error: cannot convert ‘WireSeg’ to ‘WireSeg*’ in assignment

I don't get it. `parentWireSeg` has been declared as a `WireSeg` type pointer and `wireSeg[i]` is also an element in the `wireSeg` array and is a pointer (isn't it?).

I tried playing around with it and declared `parentWireSeg` to be of type `WireSeg`:

```
struct Track {
    int trackNum;
    bool used;
    bool flag;
    WireSeg parentWireSeg;
};
```

This gave me error:

> ‘struct Track’ has no member named ‘parentWireSeg’.

This makes no sense to me either since struct `Track` does have `parentWireSeg` as an element! Can someone please explain this? Am I not allowed to have a pointer in `Track` that points to `WireSeg`?

I can probably use inherited classes (can I?) for this but I would prefer if someone told me what is wrong with my method?

Comment: Aren't you missing a semicolon on the line that says `typedef WireSeg* WireSegPtr`?  How would this even compile?

Comment: I think that is just a typo because adding the semicolon gives us the `cannot convert` error.

Comment: Please post the actual code you are using with cut & paste instead of making typos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing the line where you do the assignment to:

```
wireSeg[i].track[j].parentWireSeg = &wireSeg[i];
```

You see, wireSeg is of type `WireSeg*`, so when you dereference it by doing `*wireSeg` or `wireSeg[0]` or `wireSeg[i]`, you get something that is of type `WireSeg`.  If you want the address of the object instead of the object itself, so you can make a pointer, you need to add the address operator (&).

Comment: Oo, I guess my misunderstanding was I thought wireSeg[i] is a pointer of type WireSeg. I see my mistake now. Thanks David.

Comment: @noobuntu: one way to think of `wireSeg[i]` is `*(wireSeg + i)`. The `*` operator is certainly dereferencing a pointer, so we can see the result of `wireSeg[i]` is not a pointer (but a full object), and the result of `wireSeg + i` is a pointer.

Answer (score 1):

> wireSeg[i] is also an element in the wireSeg array and is a pointer (isn't it?).

No, `wireSeg[i]` is is a `wireSeg`, not a pointer to a `wireSeg`.

For instance, if you had an `int foo[4] = {1, 2, 3, 4}`, then `foo[0]` would be an `int`, not an `int *`, right?

You need `&wireSeg[i]` to get a pointer; or just `wireSeg + i`, as `wireSeg` can be treated as a pointer, and adding `i` is the same thing as getting the address of element `i`.